# JavaScript code keeps failing

Tags: javascript, html

I have hidden a div tag and I am using JavaScript to make that div tag appear on the screen upon form submission, the problem is that the div tag appears but then it quickly disappears, I have no idea what is going on, I need it to stop disappearing, once the form is submit the div tag should remain visible on the page, the div tag only contains a p tag with some text, I have tried onClick on the button but I get the same result.

```
<html>
<body>
        <form onSubmit="validateRadio()">

   <div  style="display: none" id="validationText"  >
        <p style="border: 1px solid black;">
        "This field is mandatory".
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
<input type="submit">
    </div>
        </form>
    </body>

       <script type="text/javascript">
   function validateRadio(){
    validationText.style.display="block";
   }
  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: when the form is submitted, the page is reloaded.

Comment: I assume the text disappears because the form is submitted and the page refreshes. Are you looking for a way to make the "mandatory" text persist after submission?

Comment: "*I have no idea what is going on*" is the key here. Don't get flummoxed... step through the problem logically and the answers begin to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is likely refreshing (the action parameter defaults to the current URL if it isn't provided) which causes the DIV to "reappear". If you would like to block the form submission, use `onSubmit` but make sure to `return false` in your method.

```
function validateRadio(){
    validationText.style.display="block";

    // returning false will prevent the form submission
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything to prevent the form from actually being submitted. Change your function to return false:

```
function validateRadio() {
    validationText.style.display = "block";
    return false;
}
```

and your handler to `<form onSubmit="return validateRadio()">`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vjpduoLy/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes..
when you submit form, a new page is loaded (or same page is reloaded)

If you will see your validationText, you did'nt submit page, for example transform your

```
     <form onSubmit="return validateRadio()">
```

and

```
 function validateRadio(){
    validationText.style.display="block";
    return false
 }
```